# Export database schema from cloud DB2 as a Service on Bluemix

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

do you have any good tip for exporting my current database schema in the DB2 as a serivce (SQLDB) on Bluemix?

I have altered my schema few times manually without using framework and now I would like to export the DDL.

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different options depending on how big the schema you created is and how much you know about sqldb/DB2:

1. Look at the metadata in the syscat views and generate it yourself (basic DDL, else too complex)
2. Connect external tools to DB2 and let them generate the DDL for your. The official DB2 utility for this is `db2look`. The GUI tool IBM Data Studio can do something similar and is linked off the sqldb management console. The [steps to connect the tools/applications outside of Bluemix to your sqldb service](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html) are described in the docs for sqldb.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the application and then click on the SQLDB service instance bound to this application you should be able to launch the SQLDB dashboard from where you can explore the export options

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-sqldb-app/

Comment: that would be for exporting the data, not the database schema